Powershell only showing connected network when scanning for connections
I am trying to find all of the available network connections using powershell. Online it says to use the command netsh wlan show networks and when I run this it will only give me the currently connected network. However, if I go to the Wi-Fi manager thing in the bottom right of windows, and then go to the network selection area and let all of them load in, it netsh wlan show networks will then return all available networks. I can't find anything on other people having this problem other than one forum post that didn't give an answer. I am running it in an administrator powershell window. Does anyone know how to fix this?
I've tried using all sorts of different powershell commands, including scanning for networks multiple times, using explorer.exe ms-availablenetworks combined with the scan (I don't know what this really does), making sure there aren't any filters, etc., but nothing works.
Commands I have tried:

netsh wlan show networks

netsh wlan show network

netsh wlan show networks mode=bssid

netsh wlan show networks mode=ssid

explorer.exe ms-availablenetworks: & netsh wlan show networks (that doesn't actually run)

Start-Process "ms-availablenetworks:"; netsh wlan show networks

ms-availablenetworks; netsh wlan show networks


None of these have worked for me.
